# Using a while loop with try catch python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to catch an invalid input by the user in this function when the user runs the program. The idea is to use a try,exception block with a while loop to ensure that the code is continuously run until a valid input is made by the user, which is 1-5.

```
def door_one():
    print("This door has many secrets let's explore it")
    print("\nMake a choice to discover something")
    print("1 2 3 4 5")
    while True:
        explore = input(" > ")
        if explore not in ("1","2","3","4","5"):
            raise Exception ("Invalid input")

        if explore == "1":
            print("You fought a bear and died")
        elif explore == "2" or explore == "3":
            print("You become superman")
        elif explore == "4":
            print(f"Dance to save your life or a bear eats you")
            suffer("HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!!!")
        elif explore == "5":
            a_file = input("Please input a file name > ")
            we_file(a_file)
            suffer("HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!!!")
```

Comment: `raise` stops execution. Just print a message and `continue`; `break` in all other cases.

Comment: @Hollay-Horváth Zsombor thanks for the advice, it works perfectly now for this function's aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against using exceptions for controlling flows. 
Instead, I would keep iterating until the value is correct and use a return statement to indicate I'm done.

```
def door_one():
    print("This door has many secrets let's explore it")
    print("\nMake a choice to discover something")
    print("1 2 3 4 5")
    while True:

        explore = input(" > ")
        if explore not in ("1","2","3","4","5"):
            continue

        if explore == "1":
            print("You fought a bear and died")
        elif explore == "2" or explore == "3":
            print("You become superman")
        elif explore == "4":
            print(f"Dance to save your life or a bear eats you")
            suffer("HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!!!")
        elif explore == "5":
            a_file = input("Please input a file name > ")
            we_file(a_file)
            suffer("HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!!!")
        return
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I didn't want to return the function but used a break statement whenever the user entered a valid choice.  I also added an error message in case the user entered a wrong choice i.e explore.